# Pathfinding Algorithm with Moveable Obstacles

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

**Research**

I have done some research on path-finding algorithms.
I have come across some; such as A* & Dijkstra.
In most of these algorithms they allow for weights for moving through certain paths.
Some even allow for negative weights.
Walls have infinite weight, since you can never move through them.

I have also read a little about path-finding algorithms where the obstacles are moving.
However, my application is a little different.
Instead of obstacles that move on their own, there are obstacles that can be moved by the algorithm.

**Question**

Is there a path-finding algorithm that accounts for moveable (weighted) objects?

**Constraints**

The algorithm needs to find the shortest path from A-to-B.
It does not need to be efficient, as the maze is relatively small.
Moveable obstacles must be weighted

Comment: Can you elaborate on moveable obstacles? Does it mean obstacles move as soon as the person starts moving from A in direction of B. And should I assume the obstacles weight does not change

Comment: _ there are obstacles that can be moved by the algorithm_ do you mean that the pathfinding algorithm can move objects to clear a path? Or is it another algorithm that does that ?  Shortest path also needs to be defined because it is dynamic.